# How to add a user input to re-calculate code in controller and then show in the same view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, forms

Looking to be pointed in the right direction. I have a simple form in my view that accepts a number. I am wanting to send the input of this to be used in a calculation in my controller and then update for the user to see in real time.

*index.html.erb*
Simple input form, followed by calculation output:

```
<%= form_with do |form| %>
<%= form.text_field :number %>
<%= form.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %> 

<%= @output %>
```

Calculation in controller:

```
@output = params[:number].to_i * 2
```

The code is just a stupid example, but the idea is: User input in the view, which I could then place in a calculation in my controller and then send back to view. I don't need a database as I don't need to store any information.

After researching, a lot of people are suggesting Ajax for this in rails? Is this the way to go or is there something in Ruby that I can use for the same effect. I've also seen Tableless Models being used. What would the best solution be here for me? I'm guessing recalculating the code in controller is the key bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with AJAX. In Rails, you can use a Stimulus controller to do that.

Below is a simple demonstration:

1. I have a controller called pages and it looks like this.

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def receive
    render json: { body: params }
  end
end
```

Then pages#index view should be like this.

```
<div class="input-form" data-controller="ajax">
  <%= form_with url: receive_path, data: { ajax_target: 'form', action: 'submit->ajax#send' } do |form| %>
    <%= form.text_field :number %>
    <%= form.submit "Submit" %>
  <% end %>
  <p data-ajax-target="output"></p>
</div>
```

It has your form and p tag with data-ajax-target="output" is the element where you display form input data.

Then you generate a new stimulus controller caller ajax and put something like this.

```
export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = ['form', 'output']
  connect() {
    console.log(this.formTarget);
    console.log(this.outputTarget);
  }

  send(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    fetch(this.formTarget.action, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { "Accept": "application/json" },
      body: new FormData(this.formTarget)
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.outputTarget.innerHTML = data.body.number * 2;
      });
  }
}
```

And you need to make sure that you define a post route.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'pages#index'
  post 'receive', to: 'pages#receive'
end
```

Hope that make sense.

Comment: Thanks for the help. However it doesn't seem to be working just yet. Inside my `HomeController < ApplicationController` I have put the `def index` and `def receive` code. Inside `home#index ` view I have pasted the input-form code. Then I have made a new controller called `ajax.rb` and pasted the ajax code, do I need to make a special Stimulus controller somehow or did you just mean a new controller called ajax.rb? Finally in routes I have, ` 
root 'home#index' 
post 'receive', to: 'home#receive' `

Comment: Update: after some Stimulus research, Made sure Stimulus is installed in Gemfile and I have placed the ajax code inside of /controllers/ajax_controller.js but still no luck

Comment: You have interpreted it in the wrong way buddy. AJAX means Asynchronous JavaScript and XML. It is the JS way of handling HTTP requests. Stimulus is a JS framework that comes with rails. That's what rails use to control JS. In your rails app, you can find app > javascript directory and inside that, you have the controller directory. That's where your Stimulus controllers will be placed.

Comment: To create a Stimulus controller, you need to run rails g stimulus your_conroller_name and it will generate a JS file inside the above-mentioned directory. In this case when you run rails g stimulus ajax and it will generate ajax_controller.js  and that's where you should put that JS snippet. Do some research on how Stimulus works. Simply what it does is handle DOM events much easier with data attributes. You can see that in pages#index view I have put some data attributes. Those are  Stimulus controllers, actions and targets.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying - works perfectly. I have one more question if you wouldn't mind. In Home#index controller, I have a variable: `target = 13.5`, I then have a bunch of code that does some calculations using this variable. In my question I was using *2 just as an example. Rather then taking the users inputted value and doing the x2 calc, and then displaying that on the screen. I would like to update the `target` variable with whatever the user has submitted in the field.  I'm guessing in my Ajax controller I need to define the input as a variable and then pass this to my Home#index?

Comment: Does it mean your final output is based on all those calculations? If so, move them into the stimulus controller. Interpret the logic in JS instead of ruby.

Answer (score 0):

Parameters send from the browser to a Ruby on Rails app are available to the controller via the [`params`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#parameters) method.

Your controller method will likely look like this:

```
@output = params[:number].to_i * 2
```

Note: I also added a [`to_i`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/String.html#method-i-to_i) to ensure that the user input is not used in its string representation, but actually translated into a number.

Comment: Thanks for confirming how to pull the data from the form - I've updated the code with this. I do still ask the question, if this is the best way to do what I want? Does this form_with method require a database etc to work? As I was looking for a solution that didn't require this. Thanks